# Pegar um arquivo especifico em um diretorio FTP

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho dois métodos, um envia um arquivo por FTP e o outro consome um arquivo por FTP.

Os arquivos tem o nome dinâmico  `DateTime.Now` cada dia um novo arquivo.
exemplo: coletas-04-04-2017 16_00_19.xlsx

No método de Envio pego a data atual e dou um getFile(); isso me retorna sempre o arquivo do dia, independente da hora.

```
string DataAtual = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");

//pathArquivoConsumido = local onde o arquivo esta que sera enviado;
DirectoryInfo objDiretorio = new DirectoryInfo(pathArquivoConsumido);
FileInfo[] arquivoData = objDiretorio.GetFiles("Coleta_" + DataAtual + "*.csv");
```

Agora no método de consumo dos Arquivos, gostaria de fazer a mesma coisa que a linha `FileInfo[] arquivoData = objDiretorio.GetFiles("Coleta_" + DataAtual + "*.csv"); faz, só que no Diretório FTP`

Esta é a linha que consumo o arquivo, mas aqui já tenho que passar o nome completo,

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(pathFull);
```

sendo assim impossível pegar somente pela data`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É necessário fazer uma requisição para o FTP usando o método **`ListDirectoryDetails`**, o retorno desta requisição vai ser o nome de todos os arquivos (e diretórios) separados por uma quebra de linha.

Depois disso é só trabalhar com o que foi retornado, por exemplo, fazer um `Split` e criar um *array* com o nome de todos os arquivos e baixar os que forem necessários.

Segue um exemplo.

```
var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.seusite.com/pasta");  
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;  

request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("usuario", "senha");    
var response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();  

var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();  
var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);  
string arquivos = reader.ReadToEnd();

reader.Close();  
response.Close(); 

var arrayArquivos = names.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, 
                                    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

foreach(var arquivo in arrayArquivos.Where(a => a.StartsWith($"Coleta_{DataAtual}" 
                                             && a.EndsWith(".csv").ToList())
{
    Download(arquivo);
}
```